# Update contact image Freshdesk API with powershell

Tags: powershell, rest, freshdesk

Trying to update contacts in Freshdesk with Powershell and simple updates of fields work great.
Now I'd like to update the conatacts avatar/image but struggling with multipart/form-data.

I'm using Powershell 7 Core.

this is the code so far

```
    # Set global variables
$userEmail = "user.name@domain.se"
$myDomain = "domain"
$APIKey = '1234678910111213'
$EncodedCredentials = [Convert]::ToBase64String([Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(("{0}:{1}" -f $APIKey,$null)))
$HTTPHeaders = @{}
$HTTPHeaders.Add('Authorization', ("Basic {0}" -f $EncodedCredentials))
$jpgfile= 'C:\temp\scripts\Freshdesk\UserName.jpg'

#Get ID for User
$GET_URL = "https://$myDomain.freshdesk.com/api/v2/contacts?email=$userEmail"
$user=Invoke-RestMethod -Method GET -Uri $GET_URL -Headers $HTTPHeaders
$fd_id = $user.id

#Update User
$HTTPHeaders.Add('Content-Type', 'multipart/form-data')

$Image = [convert]::ToBase64String((get-content $jpgfile -AsByteStream))
$Update_URL="https://$myDomain.freshdesk.com/api/v2/contacts/$fd_id"
$UserAttributes = @{}
$customAttributes = @{}
$avatarAttributes = @{}
$UserAttributes.Add('name', 'User Name')
$UserAttributes.Add('job_title' , 'Boss')
$UserAttributes.Add('email' , $userEmail)
$customAttributes.Add('department', 'IT')
$customAttributes.Add('Subdepartment', 'Development')
$UserAttributes += @{'custom_fields' = $customAttributes}
$UserAttributes += @{'avatar' = $image}

$JSON = $UserAttributes | ConvertTo-Json

Invoke-RestMethod -Method PUT -Uri $Update_URL -Headers $HTTPHeaders -Body $JSON
```

From the API docs at https://developers.freshdesk.com/api/#contacts

This API request must have its Content-Type set to multipart/form-data.

```
Sample code | Curl
curl -v -u user@yourcompany.com:test -F 'avatar=@/path/to/image.ext' -F 'job_title=Superhero' -X PUT 'https://domain.freshdesk.com/api/v2/contacts/434'
```

Comment: If I look at [the docs](https://developers.freshdesk.com/api/#update_contact_with_avatar), the avatar property should be a path to an image file, not the imagadata itself cnverted to base64..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok seems you can use -form now in powershell core.
Invoke-RestMethod -Method PUT -Uri $Update_URL -Headers $HTTPHeaders -Form @{avatar=(Get-Item $jpgfile)}